# Sequential calling HTTP request and process loading animation in subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am working on a angular 4.4.4 application, in which merchants can give away points to customer; for that I an giving httpclient srevice call (for this I am using `cancateMap` although not sure what to use).

I have multiple merchants and all can give points to user so I want to call httpClient req sequentially for each merchant(one after another).In response I want to show points in view increases like counter and loading bar while points being added. e.g. **

> if starbucks add 20 points then in response view should show points
>   incrementing till 20 and determinant loader will be shown till it
>   completes 100%. I want to show this for each and every request

For loader I am using materials determinant loader
**:
Below is my Component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedService } from '../services/shared.service';
import { CommonService } from '../services/common.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './onboarding.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./onboarding.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  public merchantsList: Object[];
  public points: number = 0;
  public counter: number = 0;
  public merchantName: string;
  public percentage: number;
  constructor(private router: Router, private commonService: CommonService, private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.merchantsList = this.sharedService.getMerchants();
    this.transferPoints();

  }

  transferPoints() {
    let data = {
      "points": 20,
      "issueToPartyName": "O=User1,L=New York,C=US",
      "issuerBankPartyRef": "1"
    };

    Observable.of(...this.merchantsList)
      .concatMap((merchant: Object) => {
        return this.commonService.getAllMerchatPoints(merchant, data).map((res) => {
          return res
        });
      }).subscribe((res) => {

        let timer = Observable.interval(200).subscribe(() => {
          this.merchantName = res.initiator;
          this.points++;
          this.counter++;
          this.percentage = (this.counter / 20) * 100;
          if (this.percentage === 100) {
            timer.unsubscribe();
            this.percentage = 0;
            this.counter = 0;
          }
        });
      });
  }
}
```

transferPoints() is the method I am calling to give sequential http call using concateMap then in its subscribe I am getting points transferred and merchants name:

HTML is :

```
<div class="mobile-img">
  <div class="home-card flex-container flex-col-direction flex-center-center">
    <div>
      <img class="icon" src="assets/images/user-big.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="amount">{{points}}</div>
      <div class="subtext">Points</div>
    </div>

    <div class="state">Fetching your reward points...</div>

    <div class="vendor">{{merchantName|| 'Uber'}}</div>

    <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="{{percentage}}"></mat-progress-bar>
  </div>
</div>
```

and service code is :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { LoaderService } from './loader.service';
interface NodeResponse {
  name: string;
  nodeName: string;
  nodeType: string;
  port: number;
  initiator?:string;
}


@Injectable()
export class CommonService extends HttpClient {
  private contextPath = "url";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public httpHandler: HttpHandler, public loaderService: LoaderService) {

  }
  getAllNodes(): Observable<NodeResponse[]> {
    return this.http.get<NodeResponse[]>(`${this.contextPath}:10007/api/transferpoints/getAllNodesInfo`);
  }

  getAllMerchatPoints(merchant, data): Observable<NodeResponse> {
   return this.http.put<NodeResponse>(`${this.contextPath}:${merchant.port}/api/transferpoints/issueandtransfer`, data);
  }
}
```

getAllMerchatPoints is the service that I am calling

Problem is I am not able to get data from each request sequentially.I mean when http req related to starbucks finishes i want to increment points and show loaded like its fetching points; after finishing starbucks req, uber req should fire and further want to increment points and show loaded like its fetching points.

I have tried below in subscribe; used interval because I want to show loader to move till end ;however its not working properly.

```
    let timer = Observable.interval(200).subscribe(() => {
              this.merchantName = res.initiator;
              this.points++;
              this.counter++;
              this.percentage = (this.counter / 20) * 100;
              if (this.percentage === 100) {
                timer.unsubscribe();
                this.percentage = 0;
                this.counter = 0;
      }
   });
```

Am I using correct operator ? concateMap ? Is there any alternative to achieve above ?

Comment: try and `flat or merge map` [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx/rxjs)

Comment: @RahulSingh I will have multiple requests(may be 5-6) to process; how shall i do that in flatmap ? bit confuse

Comment: i have attached a link to the comment please check that

Comment: my service calls are independent of each other...

Comment: then go for [forkjoin](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx/rxjs) if they are independent

Comment: for forkjoin I have to wait for all those req to fulfill and then proceed further; quite time consuming..have already tried...and also even in forjoin success, I want to show fetching kind of thing like loader for each merchant that would be again async..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mapping operator**

Using `concatMap` vs `flatMap` in your app depends if you want to keep the ordering of merchants.
Remember http is async, so likely some calls will be responding quicker than others. `concatMap` keeps the original ordering, whereas `flatMap` emits as soon as response arrives.

Otherwise, they both do the same job - unwind inner observables.

**Timer**

Although technically nothing wrong with the timer code, I think it's confusing the picture. Basically, the http responses are not going to arrive smoothly, so unless you **know** that responses will always take less than 200ms, you can't expect this timer to be emitting at 200ms intervals.

**Results of Observable.of(...this.merchantsList).concatMap(**

> not able to get data from each request sequentially

You explained what you want to get, but not what you **are** getting. I can't see why you wouldn't get sequential results, especially using `concatMap`.

Try commenting out the timer code and put in a `console.log(res)` to see what order of responses you get.

> .. so two intervals are running concurrently as they are async !..
>   wondering is there any way to run interval also sequentially

So, I think this block within the outer subscribe

```
let timer = Observable.interval(200).subscribe(() => {
  ...
}
```

runs fast and returns back to the next merchant response. The inner subscription is running independently (as you say async). Without that interval wrapper, the inner part would run synchronously, and everything would be in sequence. But I guess you want a small delay for the correct on-screen effect.

Maybe you need the interval outside the subscribe instead of inside, like this

```
}).delay(200).subscribe((res) => {
```

**Using combineLatest()**

This is what I have so far for this approach.

```
const merchantPoints$ = Observable.of(...this.merchantsList)
  .concatMap((merchant: Object) => {
    return this.commonService.getAllMerchatPoints(merchant, data).map((res) => {
      return res
    });
  });
const timer$ = Observable.interval(200);  
Observable.combineLatest(merchantPoints$, timer$)
  .subscribe(combined => {
    const res = combined[0];
    this.merchantName = res.initiator;
    this.points++;
    this.counter++;
    this.percentage = (this.counter / 20) * 100;
    if (this.percentage === 100) {
    //   timer.unsubscribe();
      this.percentage = 0;
      this.counter = 0;
    }
  });
```

Comment: I am getting http response sequentially ,problem is in interval code. e.g. when i get response for lets say uber first, then interval starts for uber to display name and points; by the time ubers interval finishes ; second merchants response arrives and its interval starts.. so two intervals are running concurrently as they are async !.. wondering is there any way to run interval also sequentially !

Comment: Why I am using **Observable.interval** ? Because I want to show fetching points kind of loader, for which i need to calculate how many points added till now and its percentage of completion so than loader will show progress till 100% for one merchant and then continue to another merchant same way so that I can show on view like fetching points for uber after than starbucks and so on one after another !

Comment: But what happens that above interval runs simultaneously (which is obvious) and I see names and loader flickers badly and wrong name displayed. Can it be dont in other way than interval ? hope u got my issue  !

Comment: Did you try using `delay(200)` as I suggested?

Comment: Ok, so a more complicated approach is `combineLatest()` of interval and results. Will post code shortly.

Comment: Ok..will give a try !